# Rare cases of bivariate probability distributions

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

What would be a special case of a discrete bivariate probability distribution that two events are dependent but also have a covariance of zero?

Comment: Events or random variables?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose each of the following pairs have probability $\frac13$

```
X Y
1 1
2 2
3 1
```